# Parsing Boolean selector to a data frame in my function

Tags: python, pandas

Python 3.6

I'd like to be able to have a function that takes a Boolean selector for a pandas DataFame. pandas use's the `[]` slice syntax, which I cant seem to replicate in a function.

I guess I'd like to know.

What function gets called when you type?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(<data>)

result = df.<somecolumn>[<Boolean selector>]
```

I'd like to write a function that does this:

```
def apply_selector(df, column, selector):
    return df.column.<a function>(selector) # <a function> represents a conceived function that pandas executes when the `[]` slice syntax is used with a Boolean selector
```

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#) This is what i'm trying to achieve, through a function.

[image]

Comment: How should the function be called? `apply_selector(df, 'some col', 'x > 0')`?

Comment: yep ^^ just like that

Comment: look at `pd.query`https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html

Comment: @Wen that's spot on!

Comment: @JamesSchinner you can accept Psidom's answer ~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try implement your function using `query`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B': [2,2,2,4,4]})

def apply_selector(df, column, selector):
    return df.query(selector)[column]

apply_selector(df, 'A', 'A >= 3')

#2    3
#3    4
#4    5
#Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Awesome, sometimes its just hard to find what you want  in the docs when you struggle to even describe what you want to do! Thanks!!!

Comment: Yeah , this is what I think , you made it ~ ~+1